# .html only returning internal content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do not have much experience with jQuery and I think this is very minor issue. I am trying to get `html` of an element including its self. But it is returning only internal content of selected element. 
For example I have implemented this on `li`tag but I am able to get its internal content only with this. How I can get complete html 
For example this is my html

```
<li class="selected_li"> <span> some text </span> </li>
```

and this is jQuery

```
 jQuery(".selected_li").html();
```

So it is returning only span and its text but I want to get complete html which is

```
<li class="selected_li"> <span> some text </span> </li>
```

How I can get this. Is there a different jQuery function to get this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using `outerHTML`

```js
 console.log($(".selected_li")[0].outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="selected_li"> <span> some text </span> </li>
</ul>
```